Why do VAEs work?
I am currently reading into Variational Autoencoders, and although I kind of understand the mathematical background described in the original paper (Auto-encoding Variational Bayes), I am struggling to understand why training a VAE actually works.
When training a VAE, we don't simply reconstruct the image from the output from the encoder, but rather from a sample drawn from a distribution parameterized by the encoders output. In doing so we do not only optimize for a reconstruction loss, but also the KL regularization term which wants the posterior $q(z|x)$ to be close to $p(z)$, where $p(z)$ is some simple predefined distribution like a gaussian. As far as I understand, the KL divergence regularization will simply try to pull the encoders mean output towards the $\mathbf{0}$ vector, and the variance towards the $\mathbf{1}$ vector. When that term becomes zero we encounter the posterior collapse because obviously the latents $z$ become totally random (i.e. because $z = \mu + \epsilon \cdot \sigma = \epsilon$ and the decoder just ignores them. And this is what I don't get: if we end up with a posterior collapse, if the encoders output get to close to the isotropic gaussian, why does sampling from an isotropic gaussian work for generating new images?
I did some digging but couldn't find any explanations. Maybe I am looking for the wrong thing, so in case this is a duplicate or there are other resources explaining that, I'd be happy to be pointed into the right direction.

Posterior collapse occurs when the encoder learns to output a distribution $q(z∣x)$ that is almost the same for all inputs $x$ in the case that the KL term becomes very small during training, which essentially makes $z$ behave like random noise drawn from the prior distribution $p(z)$ rather than carrying any useful information about the input data.
But the goal of VAE training is not just to make $q(z∣x)$ close to $p(z)$, but also to structure the latent space such that points sampled from $p(z)$ lead to valid data distributions after passing through the decoder, even the learned latent space collapsed to $p(z)$. After training, the decoder already learns to map samples from this simple prior to meaningful data points like images. The problem with posterior collapse is that the model isn't learning useful latent representations, thus it fails to generalize well to unseen data. While this doesn’t prevent the decoder from generating samples from the prior, it makes the model less generalizable and reduces its ability to perform reconstruction task or transfer learning from the same data distribution in a more versatile yet realistic way.

Thanks! I think I understand it now a bit better. Something that still confuses me is how the model learns "meaningful" parameters of a distribution. Lets say we sample z = mu + sigma * eps. Then, if the gradients want to pull z somehow to z' it influences both mu and sigma. But does the update of the parameters actually relate to mu and sigma as the mean and standard deviation?

This natural confusion is why vaes stochastic back propagation training requires the reparameterization trick to ensure the updated parameters of the encoder network are actually the mean and standard deviation of a multivariate gaussian. With proper ideal regularization from the kl term without posterior collapse, close data points in the original data distribution will be also close in the meaningfully leaned latent space. But if posterior collapse occurs, even very different data points from two different training sets will be very close in latent space as over regularization.
